# Js array of object group by value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this

```
[{id: 151, parent: null}
{id: 152, parent: 151}
{id: 153, parent: 151} 
{id: 158, parent: null}
{id: 159, parent: 158}
{id: 160, parent: null}
{id: 161, parent: 160}]
```

So what i want to get is new array like this

```
[
[{id: 151, parent: null}
{id: 152, parent: 151}
{id: 153, parent: 151} ]
[{id: 158, parent: null}
{id: 159, parent: 158} ]
[{id: 151, parent: null}
{{id: 160, parent: null}
{id: 161, parent: 160} ]
]
```

i tried to used this but not working

```
 for (let i=0; i<arrays.length; i+=1) {
if (arrays [i].parent === null){
 index.push(arrays[i]);
 }
}
```

Thank for help

Comment: What do you think `if (i < arrays [i].parent === null)` is supposed to do...?

Comment: I corrected  if (arrays [i].parent === null){}

Comment: I dont understand how the response should look like, there is no coma, nothing, please format it.

Comment: is it in sorted form?

Comment: @PrinceHernandez i would group the id by parent

Comment: @Shubham yes yes !

Comment: @PrinceHernandez yes

Comment: can you have a greater depth than one?

Comment: what exactly is the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I'll bite.

```js
const input = [
  {id: 151, parent: null},
  {id: 152, parent: 151},
  {id: 153, parent: 151} ,
  {id: 158, parent: null},
  {id: 159, parent: 158},
  {id: 160, parent: null},
  {id: 161, parent: 160}
];
const sorted = input
    .filter(item=>item.parent === null)
    .map(root=>[root, ...input.filter(item=>item.parent === root.id)]);

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd","<pre>"+JSON.stringify(sorted,null,2)+"</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this in two steps. First get the null parents into the resulting array and then adding the corresponding "children" to the correct array.

```
let arr =[
    {id: 151, parent: null},
    {id: 152, parent: 151},
    {id: 153, parent: 151}, 
    {id: 158, parent: null},
    {id: 159, parent: 158},
    {id: 160, parent: null},
    {id: 161, parent: 160}
]
let result = [];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].parent == null){
        result.push([arr[i]]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].parent!=null){
        // console.log(arr[i])
        for(c=0;c<result.length;c++){
            if(result[c][0].id == arr[i].parent){
                result[c].push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

The result of this would be:

```
[
  [
    { id: 151, parent: null },
    { id: 152, parent: 151 },
    { id: 153, parent: 151 }
  ],
  [ { id: 158, parent: null }, { id: 159, parent: 158 } ],
  [ { id: 160, parent: null }, { id: 161, parent: 160 } ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not super-elegant, but it should do the trick:

```
const x = [
  {id: 151, parent: null},
  {id: 152, parent: 151},
  {id: 153, parent: 151} ,
  {id: 158, parent: null},
  {id: 159, parent: 158},
  {id: 160, parent: null},
  {id: 161, parent: 160}
];

const sorted = x.reduce((value, _) => {
  const existing = value.find(v => v.length && v[0].id === _.parent);
  return existing
    ? [...value.filter(v => v !== existing), [...existing, _]]
    : [...value, [_]];
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid using lambdas, here are some steps to create a map-like object for your nested objects.

you can adapt the structure of the resulted object to your needs

```js
result = [];

for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    let obj = array[i];

    //check if the obj has any parent
    if (obj.parent == null){ 

        //if not, add it as parent if it's not already added
         if( result[obj.id] == undefined ){
             result[obj.id] = [];   
         }
     } else { //else add it as child
        if( result[obj.parent] == undefined ){
            result[obj.parent] = []; // create the parent if not existing
        }
        result[obj.parent].push(obj);
     }
}
```